# нужно обрезать и записать только слово после двоеточия регуляркой

Tags: javascript

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;

  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Записано в гугл док";
  sendText(id,answer);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);
}
```

таким образом записываю с телеграмма сообщение в гугл таблицу.
Сообщения приходят в таком виде:

Имя: юрий

Телефон: 899999

Почта: ya@yandex.ru

Выберите количество комнат: 1-комнатная

Выберите тип отделки: С отделкой

Желаемый способ оплаты: Рассрочка

Как можно обрезать текст и  записать только все что находится после двоеточия (1-комнатная), строки Выберите количество комнат. Расположение строки по счету может меняться.

C регулярными выражениями не очень дружу, по этому прошу помощи

Comment: зачем вы откатили правку? в оригинале у Вас строки, а не сплошной текст. Оформите правильно (строка с новой строки).

Comment: сможете помочь сделать?

Comment: Вам нужно вывести текстом в одну строку все, что находится в каждой строке после двоеточия, т.е. `юрий 899999 ya@yandex.ru 1-комнатная С отделкой Рассрочка` ?

Comment: нет,  только то что находится после двоеточия

Comment: я например ничегоо не понял, можно посмотреть четко, что есть и что нужно получить, на примере, без таких объяснений

Comment: и  вот здесь SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(),id,name,text,answer]);  text это одна чека дока.  а эти значения желательно записывать отдельными ячейками

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы так

```
$str = 'Имя: юрий

Телефон: 899999

Почта: ya@yandex.ru

Выберите количество комнат: 1-комнатная

Выберите тип отделки: С отделкой

Желаемый способ оплаты: Рассрочка';


preg_match_all('{\b\pL+:\s*(.+)\b}u', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr[1]);
```

В результате работы кода получится следующая строка:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 'юрий' 
  1 => '899999' 
  2 => 'ya@yandex.ru' 
  3 => '1-комнатная' 
  4 => 'С отделкой' 
  5 => 'Рассрочка'
```

---

Далее, если нужно полученный результат преобразовать в строку, и вывести в таблице (как на вашем скрине), то нужно использовать цикл

```
preg_match_all('{\b\pL+:\s*(.+)\b}u', $str, $arr);

$view = '<table border="1"><tr>';

foreach ($arr[1] as $string) {
    $view .= "<td>$string</td>";
}

$view .= '</tr></table>';

echo $view;
```

Comment: эти значения которые приходят после двоеточие всегда разные. не измены только до :   то есть в следующем тексте может быть 2-комнатная

Comment: а вот как бы на js сделать?)

Comment: @Stiks2203 в  js я не силён, кто-то другой подскажет )

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Имя: юрий

Телефон: 899999

Почта: ya@yandex.ru

Выберите количество комнат: 1-комнатная

Выберите тип отделки: С отделкой

Желаемый способ оплаты: Рассрочка';
preg_match_all('/\:\s(.*)/', $string, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Результат

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "юрий"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "899999"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "ya@yandex.ru"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "1-комнатная"
  [4]=>
  string(20) "С отделкой"
  [5]=>
  string(18) "Рассрочка"
}
```

**UPDATE**

Посмотрел [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/). Оказывается там используется только `RegExp.exec()`. А в `RegExp.exec()` вы не можете получать все регулярное выражение одновременно. Вам понадобится добавить все отдельно!

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var text = data.message.text;

  var id = data.message.chat.id;
  var name = data.message.chat.first_name + " " + data.message.chat.last_name;
  var answer = "Записано в гугл док";
  sendText(id, answer);
  var fname = /Имя: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  var phone = /Телефон: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  var email = /Почта: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  var room = /Выберите количество комнат: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  var type = /Выберите тип отделки: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  var payment = /Желаемый способ оплаты: (.+)/.exec(text)[1].replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*)$/g, '');
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[0].appendRow([new Date(), id, name, answer, fname, phone, email, room, type, payment]);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74196/discussion-on-answer-by-kyran--------).